# Why does my http request body doesn't get transferred to the server?

Tags: http, post, dart, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

I have made an ajax http post request and tried it in Fiddler and it worked, but when I tried to run the exact same request in Dart the request body doesn't got transferred to the server. Is something wrong with my Dart request body?

```
Response response = await client.post(
      'https://intranet.tam.ch/krm/timetable/ajax-get-timetable',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Language': 'de-ch',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Host': 'intranet.tam.ch',
        'Origin': 'https://intranet.tam.ch',
        'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'https://intranet.tam.ch/krm/calendar',
        'Content-Length': '83',
        'Cookie':
            'school=krm; sturmsession=xx; sturmuser=xx; username=xx',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      },
      body:
          'startDate=1597615200000&endDate=598133600000&studentId%5B%5D=x&holidaysOnly=0');


client.close();

print(response.body);
```

Any answers are highly appreciated

Comment: How does the rest of your method look like? Have you tried to print `response.body` to see if the server gives you some kind of response?

Comment: I printed the ```response.body``` and it said that the POST Parameter "startDate" is missing even tough it is present in the body.

Comment: Try remove `'Content-Length': '83',` from your header. (it will automatically be added again by the library but it seems to make some problems if you already have a "Content-Length" in your header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of strange behavior if you define `Content-Length` in the header manually where the body are never going to be sent. If you remove the header and lets the library handle the `Content-Length` it works.